# AWS Cognito: how to deny Login to a user if it is not part of the user pool?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I want to deny login to a user if it tries to login when its username and password is not registered in the userpool. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @KaiBurjack there are 2 login pages, Manager and employee, both made with AmplifyAuthenticator. I don't want an employee registered in the user pool be able to login through manager login page.

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the use of a [pre-authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html) Lambda trigger here.

Since you mention there are two pages (manager and employee), I believe the architecture is such that the manager login page and the employee login page uses different app clients. So basically two app clients in a single user pool.

A pre-auth trigger as the name suggests is triggered right before the login. Inside this Lambda function, you need to write code to check if the request is coming from the manager's app client, and if so reject the login. An example is provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html#aws-lambda-triggers-pre-authentication-example).